# Printing on Windows isn't working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, printing

I'm working on a C++ script to print directly on Windows.

Currently I'm using following code from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162959(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
BOOL RawDataToPrinter(LPTSTR szPrinterName, LPBYTE lpData, DWORD dwCount)
{
    BOOL     bStatus = FALSE;
    HANDLE     hPrinter = NULL;
    DOC_INFO_1 DocInfo;
    DWORD      dwJob = 0L;
    DWORD      dwBytesWritten = 0L;

    bStatus = OpenPrinter(szPrinterName, &hPrinter, NULL);

    if (bStatus) {
        // Fill in the structure with info about this "document." 
        DocInfo.pDocName = (LPTSTR)_T("My Document");
        DocInfo.pOutputFile = NULL;
        DocInfo.pDatatype = (LPTSTR)_T("RAW");

        // Inform the spooler the document is beginning. 
        dwJob = StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, (LPBYTE)&DocInfo);
        if (dwJob > 0) {
            // Start a page. 
            bStatus = StartPagePrinter(hPrinter);

            if (bStatus) {
                // Send the data to the printer. 
                bStatus = WritePrinter(hPrinter, lpData, dwCount, &dwBytesWritten);
                EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // Inform the spooler that the document is ending. 
            EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // Close the printer handle. 
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);

        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    // Check to see if correct number of bytes were written. 
    if (!bStatus || (dwBytesWritten != dwCount)) {
        bStatus = FALSE;
    }
    else {
        bStatus = TRUE;
    }
    return bStatus;
}
```

And I'm calling the method with:

```
std::string str = "Hello World";
BOOL blubb = RawDataToPrinter((LPTSTR)_T("PRINTER_NAME"), (LPBYTE) str.c_str(), str.size());
```

The problem I have is that the print job is display for a few milliseconds (just long enough to see) in the printing queue of my printer, but he doesn't print anything.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `sizeof(str)` will *not* give you what you expect (the length of the contained string). For that use `str.size()`.

Comment: I tried it, but i got the same result as earlier

Comment: Why do you need `(LPTSTR)` cast? Just `_T("PRINTER_NAME")` should be enough. Also is it not an option to use `CreateDC` for direct printing?

Comment: I used the cast because the sample code provides it. And I don't know, if I need to use `CreateDC`.

Comment: I can't spot an error with your code. I mean if you just want to bypass the print dialog then use `HDC hdc = CreateDC(L"WINSPOOL", L"Printer Name", NULL, NULL); StartDoc, StartPage, TextOut(hdc,...)` (this doesn't have anything to do with RAW)

Comment: Try debugging your program. Find out where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

In 2004, I have encountered a lof of problem to print document from C++ program. I have tried to used Windows MFC API but this don't work well. So I have found another solution that continues to work in 2018 using Visual Studio 2017 !

```
 XString sCmd;
 XString sDevice = "\\\\localhost\\DefaultPrinter";

 sCmd.Clear() << "net use LPT1: " << sDevice;
 iRetCode = system(sCmd);

 sCmd.Clear() << "print /D:LPT1 " << sFile;
 iRetCode = system(sCmd);

 sCmd = "net use LPT1: /delete";
 iRetCode = system(sCmd);
```

The class XString is a clone of MFC CString enhanced so that code work on Windows and BS2000 (Siemens Operating System = Betrieb System in german).

This code work only if you define a shared printed named "DefaultPrinter" on each PC where C++ EXE must run.

Without using XString, and in simplifying some lines, the code can be:

```
std::string sDevice = "\\\\localhost\\DefaultPrinter";

system(string("net use LPT1: ") + sDevice);
system(string("print /D:LPT1 ") + sFileToPrint;
system("net use LPT1: /delete");
```